# Permission issues on building projects in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

So i'm really annoyed about this. After months and months of going back and forth with employees at Microsoft, I'm just about ready to give up on this.

So here's the deal. Ever since Microsoft released a new update to VS 2017 a few months ago my project has not been building. I get the following error:

```
Metadata file D:\Work\Unity Distributed\ISET\UnityDEng.ISET.Modules.Software\bin\Debug\UnityDEng.ISET.dll' could not be found
```

This project builds fine on other people's workstations with the same update and configuration as me. I have actually solved and fixed this issue myself by redoing the .SLN for the project but I cannot check this in to our version control system because i'm certain it will break everyone else's  builds. Both me and Microsoft support believe the error is permission related however i gave myself full control over all objects when checking it out of version control.

Has anyone had any issues like this? It would be a great help to hear your suggestions because even Microsoft are baffled at this point.

Edit: Forgot to mention that the project builds fine in VS 2015 but obviously I don't want to use 2015 whilst everyone else is using 2017.

Comment: the solution you probably have is to copy that DLL to the location it's looking for it?

Comment: That's what i would have thought. But here's the real puzzling thing. The DLL doesn't exist. On other people's builds that exact location does not exist so I have no idea what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick update: Managed to resolve the issue by downgrading Visual Studio to version 15.6.7. No idea why this fixed it but it did. I believe it may be to do with my NugGet packages not being properly compatible with 2017.